# Meaning of Elap per Exec (s) on Oracle AWR Reports

Tags: performance, oracle10g

In SQL ordered by Elapsed Time / Elap per Exec (s)  ---it is the time the result of the sql reach the client ?

I read this document How to Identify Resource Intensive SQL where

where it is defined Response Time = Service Time + Wait Time

Is the response time = elapsed time (s) ?  or is only part of the Service Time

Thanks

---

Just got this from an Oracle Forum:

(1) Elapsed Time = "CPU Time" + "Non-Idle Wait Time" + "Elapsed Time Unaccounted-for".

(2) Response Time Accounted-for = "Elapsed Time" + "Idle Wait Time".

(3) Total Response Time = "Response Time Accounted-for" + "Response Time Unaccounted-for".

Answer (score 1):

None of these timings include the time for the data to reach the client.

In practice, response time = elapsed time, more or less.

Elapsed time includes time to parse the SQL statement, execute it, and fetch the results (if it's a SELECT).

It *does* include the time that the server has to wait to read data from the disk, for example.

However, it does *not* include the network roundtrip time from client to server and back - the Oracle Server has no way to measure that.

In my experience, if you are looking for ressource-intensive SQL, the things to start with is CPU time and disk waits. If the response time is much higher that the sum of that, you are getting into advanced territory. I've never had to look at idle wait or unaccounted-for times.